# Interpretation of fixed effect model (panel data)

Tags: r, econometrics, interpretation, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am doing a work to school in which I have to analyze effect of expenditure for research and development on Gini index. I have *Panel data* and when I do *Fixed effect model*, I have problem with interpreting them. If anybody can help, I am looking for some place where I can find what each of the results I get means because I have to do other models as well.

This is what I get from fixed effect model:

```
Oneway (individual) effect Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = log(Gini) ~ log(VaR), data = data, model = "within")

Balanced Panel: n=17, T=11, N=187

Residuals :
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-0.3140 -0.0933  0.0149  0.0972  0.2270 

Coefficients :
           Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
log(VaR) -0.0272357  0.0078724 -3.4596 0.0006847 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Total Sum of Squares:    2.8467
Residual Sum of Squares: 2.6584
R-Squared      :  0.066139 
      Adj. R-Squared :  0.059773 
F-statistic: 11.9691 on 1 and 169 DF, p-value: 0.00068471
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run an econometrics-style fixed effects model, your coefficient estimate is the marginal change expected in Y after changing one unit of X, controlling for all time-invariant heterogeneity in your groups.  Your error term now only includes things that vary over time.

So say your units are countries observed over time.  If you ran pooled OLS, your error term would include things like the total amount of coastline, or whether or not a country's name includes the letter "x".  These things don't change over time.

It is the same as running a regular regression wherein you control for your cross-sectional unit (countries, in this example) as a factor variable.