# How to interpret a fixed effect model

Tags: interpretation, panel-data, stata, fixed-effects-model

I am doing a research for a school project and I have a hard time to interpret my results from a fixed effect model. So far, I found this:[Interpretation of fixed effect model (panel data)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56103/interpretation-of-fixed-effect-model-panel-data). Though, it didn't really help with how to comnine the years interpretation with the other variables.[image]

dale=adjusted life expectancy,
hc3=years of schooling,
hexp=per capita health expenditure in 1997 international dollars.

Comment: I would add the code used to fit the model as well as the full output and clarify what you understand already and what you are struggling with. This will improve the odds that you will get any sort of answer.

Comment: Agreed w/ @DimitriyV.Masterov. Without knowing that, my best guess is that the hc3 and hexp coefficients are telling you about differences in your outcome associated with a 1-unit difference in these variables, within-country and within-year. So within a given country and year, a 1-unit difference in hc3 relative to another observation in that same year and country is associated with a .877 increase in dale.